# Listen to keydown event to identify which node will get focus before UI response

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, contenteditable, keydown

Imagine a contenteditable div with various content and multiple node types and lines.
The caret is currently on the second line anchored/focused to a `<p>` node.

```
document.getSelection().focusNode
```

The `up arrow key` is pushed and the caret moves to the first line and is anchored/focus to some random node just "above" the previously focused `<p>` node.

How could I capture an event such as 'keydown', to identify the destination node before the browser UI moves the caret to that position?

The aim is to disallow the caret to move to certain positions, avoiding UI glitches.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo to hopefully get you started. This demo is working tracking mouse clicks, but you can adapt it to listen for `keydown` events and intercept the arrow keys *before* cursor focus changes. The idea is this.

1. Use an HTML class to identify the cool and uncool elements in which a user can click on and retain cursor focus.
2. Create a JavaScript array containing cool (1) and uncool (0) positions for which a user can gain focus.
3. If the user clicks on an uncool block after a cool block, the focus returns to the last cool block that was clicked. If the user clicks an uncool block *first* (before anything else was clicked), simply blur the focus away from the uncool position.

```js
var positions = [];
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".container > div");
var current_elem = null;

[].forEach.call(elems, function(elem, index) {
  positions.push(elem.classList.contains('cool') ? 1 : 0);
  
  elem.addEventListener("click", function checkPosition() {
    if (positions[index] === 1) {
      current_elem = index+1;
    } else {
      if (current_elem !== null) {
        document.querySelector('.container div:nth-child(' + current_elem + ')').focus();
      } else {
        this.blur();
      }
    }
  });  
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}
.container > div {
  background: lightgray;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 0;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

div.uncool {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.container,
div.cool:after,
div.uncool:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
}

div.cool:after {
  content: 'cool';
}

div.uncool:after {
  content: 'uncool';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div tabindex="0" class="cool"></div>
  <div tabindex="0" class="uncool"></div>
  <div tabindex="0" class="uncool"></div>
  <div tabindex="0" class="cool"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had a similar approach, but the issue is the UI glitch. It is still possible to get focus on the wanted element for a very limited period of time which in the case of a contenteditable div, it is prone to allow changes on the "uncool" elements if you're typing pretty fast.